# StaticResource priority in Windows Phone 8

Tags: design-patterns, windows-phone-8, resourcedictionary

I have a base styles files that contains all by base colors and base font settings. Then I have 2 other resource dictionaries that use that the initial resource.

I have it setup as follows:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <localization:LocalizationLocator x:Key="LocalizedStrings" />
        <viewModels:ViewModelLocater x:Key="VmLocator" />
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="\Resources\Styles\BaseStyles.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="\Resources\Styles\FormInputStyles.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="\Resources\Styles\OtherControllsStyles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then I get the following exception from FormInputStyles.xml

`Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key MyNewAccentColor [Line: 17 Position: 44]`

Is there a way to load the BaseStyles.xaml before adding merged dictionaries?

(I know I could have them all in the same file but I would like my styles broken down so that I can have better code re-use)

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried this myself, but [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh968442.aspx) page says:

`If multiple merged dictionaries exist, these dictionaries are checked in the inverse of the order in which they are declared in the MergedDictionaries property.`

I.e. try to put BaseStyles.xaml as last element.

And please also check this SO question: [Proper usage of Merged Resource Dictionaries in Silverlight 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226436/proper-usage-of-merged-resource-dictionaries-in-silverlight-3)